# Java spring boot basic authentication with redis

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

I'm trying to add authentication layer into my spring boot application, and all the tutorials i can find are with some mock user, such as:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
   auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("learn").password("share").roles("USER");
}
```

I would like to implement something like this:

```
String credentials = request.getHeader('Authorization');
String userName = fetchUserName(credentials);
String password = fetchUserPassword(credentials);
String actualPassword = redis.getPassowrdForUser(userName);
if (actualPassword == someHash(password)) {
   // continue with the request
} else {
   // return unauthorised request 401
}
```

Thanks.

---

This is my current implementation, from some tutorial i've found:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BasicAuthenticationPoint authEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/signup").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("learn").password("share").roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}



@Component
public class BasicAuthenticationPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authEx)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=" +getRealmName());
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("HTTP Status 401 - " + authEx.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        setRealmName("learn");
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

}
```

Comment: it is far from finish, you should implement by yourself

Comment: can you point me out to the method where i fetch data from redis and validate it?
i'll do the rest.